# How to add WAF to my cognito UserPool with cdk

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-cdk, amazon-waf, aws-userpools

I can't find examples or [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cognito-readme.html) about how to use cdk to attach a waf to a cognito userpool.

Comment: We can attach WAF only to  Cloudfront distribution and Application Loadbalancer only. Why do you need to attach WAF to Cognito Userpool?

Comment: yes you can, if you go on "User pool properties" you can attach an AWS WAF to it. The purpopse is to add security.

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like there is no API in Cognito Userpool you will need to create CfnWebACLAssociation and provide the Userpool ARN for the resource ARN. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_wafv2.CfnWebACLAssociation.html#resourcearn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API in Cognito Userpool. You will need to create CfnWebACLAssociation and provide the Userpool ARN for the resource ARN.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_wafv2.CfnWebACLAssociation.html#resourcearn

```
import { aws_wafv2 as wafv2 } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
const cfnWebACLAssociation = new wafv2.CfnWebACLAssociation(this, 'MyCfnWebACLAssociation', {
  resourceArn: 'arn: *partition* :cognito-idp: *region* : *account-id* :userpool/ *user-pool-id*',
  webAclArn: 'webAclArn',
});
```